# Using Java, how to add some node to an existing json at the start of array?

Tags: java, json, jsonpath

The below code inserts the "myvalue" field to the existing JSON but after the "id" key-value pair, I want to insert a value in this JSON but before the "id" field.

```
String originalJson="{"checkouts":[{"line_items":[{"id":"343f1f49d0ba7752b5ba84e0184384f4"}]}]}";
String modifiedJson= JsonPath.parse(originalJson)
                        .add("$.checkouts[0].line_items","myValue")
                        .jsonString();
```

The current output of the above code is :

```
{"checkouts":[{"line_items":[{"id":"343f1f49d0ba7752b5ba84e0184384f4"},"myValue"]}]}
```

But I want an output like this :

```
{"checkouts":[{"line_items":["myValue",{"id":"343f1f49d0ba7752b5ba84e0184384f4"}]}]}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show exactly the JSON you want to produce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
        String originalJson="{\"checkouts\":[{\"line_items\":[{\"id\":\"343f1f49d0ba7752b5ba84e0184384f4\"}]}]}";
        DocumentContext json = JsonPath.parse(originalJson);
        JSONArray array = json.read("$.checkouts[0].line_items");
        array.add(0, "myValue");
        String modifiedJson= json
                .set("$.checkouts[0].line_items",array)
                .jsonString();
```